# access json object in array after PDO fetch data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have database values as JSON. I want to get values assigned to key like "name". How can I get those in PHP?.

```
<?php

include('db.class.php');

$sql = "select * from users where 1";

$obj = new db();
$stmt = $obj->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($res,true);

echo $big = $json->name; // ??? ERROR
```

**my output is**

```
[
    {"id":"1",
    "name":"test1",
    "username":"abc",
    "email":"c@c.com",
    "phone":"333"
    },
    {"id":"2",
    "name":"test2",
    "username":"def",
    "email":"a@a.com",
    "phone":"23232"}
]
```

Comment: `$json` is a string, not an object. And there's more than one row in the results, which one are you expecting `$json->name` to return?

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo '<pre>' . print_r($res, true) . '</pre>';` so we can see what exactly is the structure of returned result

Comment: Would it not be simpler to do `$res[0]['name']`

Comment: Take a quick dip into [The PHP manual for `json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and see if parameter 2 has a TRUE option in there! Then you might like to swim over to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) just to say hello

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `json_encode()`. `$res` is an array of the results, you can access the names from that.

```
echo $res[0]['name'];
```

Note that the elements of `$res` are associative arrays, not objects, because you use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: Finally some one agree's with me

Answer (score 0):

First you decode jason array then fetch the result

```
$data= json_decode($json);

echo $data[0]->name;
```

if you need more information about jason_decode then read [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: `$data[0]->name`

Comment: Would it not be simpler to do `$res[0]['name']` and cut out all this unnecesary dancing with JSON